# How to use column name 'use' in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I've got a DB I migrated from MySQL to SQLServer.  One of the table's column names is `use`.  How can I write my insert statement to not throw an error becuase of it?  I'm getting the error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4830
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'use'.
```

My insert looks something like:

```
insert into foo (id, use, some_other_attrs) values(1, fun, other_stuff);
```

Comment: I wonder how `use` could ever be considered a _useful_ column name. Perhaps rethink _that_ first.

Comment: @GrantThomas If you think about the noun representation of `use` instead of verb, it doesn't seem so useless.

Comment: @Khan I fail to see how it explains anything, even in context with a parent name (obviously - hopefully - not `foo`) to be considered reasonable.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. [I just answered this on another site in the network](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50834/how-to-use-column-name-use-in-sqlserver).

Comment: @Khan do you also think `cost` is as descriptive as `UnitCost` or `RetailPrice`? I don't.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No sir, but I don't find any name in the question to be descriptive.  I see this as a case of running into a keyword and wondering how to handle it in the case they would like to use it.

Comment: @Khan `id` is a pretty common one that (a) I've given up fighting about and (b) doesn't cause an error like `use` does. You are arguing that use is descriptive, and I disagree, that's all.

Comment: @Khan - "but I don't find any name in the question to be descriptive" is not grounds to defend the use of `use` as a field name.

Comment: @Khan fortunately spoken languages are quite flexible so OP could use [Utility], or [Purpose] or something. why risk it by using reserved words - that just seems a bit careless.

Comment: Perhaps it's not the OP's choice? In the real world, you run into terrible naming schemes all the time, and he may not be in a position to magically wish it to be correct. If `use` is the colname, and he can't change it, why quibble about it?

Comment: @Nathaniel the discussion arose because someone suggested to ***Perhaps*** *rethink* - emphasis mine. Maybe they do have control, and maybe they didn't know `use` was a reserved word. Should we not suggest avoiding reserved words (or ambiguous or unclear words) and just assume that everyone who posts about such an issue has no control over their schema? You can feel free to do that but don't nit-pick others who disagree.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The original comment was snarky, especially considering the emphasis that commenter used. One should avoid assuming vast knowledge on the part of the user and make one's comments as kindly as possible. I would recommend "`use` is a reserved word. If possible, rename this column for maximum clarity. If not, you will need to escape it to avoid this error." There is a massive difference between 'suggest' and 'suggest with the implication you're stupid for not already knowing'.

Comment: @NathanielFord you apparently have much thinner skin than most of the IT industry. I don't see any of the assumptions or implications you do in the original comment. *shrug*

Comment: What is the purpose of re-opening this question? Does someone expect additional answers that solve the OP's problem better than the answers that already exist?

Comment: @AaronBertrand And now you've gotten personal for no particular reason? What is the rational basis for literally advocating a hostile approach to comments? Is there a defensible reason one wouldn't err on the side of politeness, such that a 'thick skin' wouldn't be a requirement to be a programmer?

Comment: If this question gets reopened, it should certainly be marked as a duplicate of another.

Comment: @NathanielFord I assure you my input was not given with the intention of coming off as "snarky", and was a legitimate attempt at getting the user to think about what could be another problem, which by solving would also solve this one. I don't understand how using oblique emphasis gives that air of snark. Emphasis is emphasis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have to put the name in `[use]`

```
insert into foo (id, [use], some_other_attrs) values(1, fun, other_stuff);
```

**On a side note:-** Do not prefer to use [Reserve keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) as column names

Answer (score 8):

`use` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) (the hint is right there in the error message!) that allows you to change database context (e.g. `USE master;`). You shouldn't use reserved words as identifiers (table names, column names, database names, users, etc).

You need to either fix the column name (I suggest something a little more descriptive and self-documenting) or surround it with square brackets (which tells SQL Server to ignore that it is a keyword). Also, [please always use the schema prefix on objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix):

```
INSERT dbo.foo(id, [use], ...) SELECT 1, 'fun', ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it with `[]`

```
insert into foo (id, [use], some_other_attrs) values(1, fun, other_stuff);
```

Stay away from reserved words for column names

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx