# MSSQL Error while adding Insert stored procedure and others too

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, sql-insert

Following code is getting error >**incorrect syntax near User**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add]
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Email NVARCHAR(50),
    @Address NVARCHAR (300)
AS
    INSERT INTO User([Name],[Email],[Address]) VALUES ("'@Name','@Email','@Address'")
RETURN 0
```

and tried below code too

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add]
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Email NVARCHAR(50),
    @Address NVARCHAR (300)
AS
    INSERT INTO User VALUES ("@Name,@Email,@Address")
RETURN 0
```

i am using following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserId]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]   NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Address] NVARCHAR (300) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)

);
```

with visual studio 2019
sql server 2016 version 13.00.4001

**i am not able to figure out problem**
so help me out here

Comment: Remove the double quotes and the single quotes in your first proc. Don't enclose parameters: `VALUES(@Name,@Email, @Address)`

Comment: Ideally, you should avoid naming any objects with reserved keywords.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use column name 'use' in sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124172/how-to-use-column-name-use-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 3):

`User` is a reserved keyword in `SQL Server`, Use square bracket :

```
INSERT INTO [User] ([Name],[Email],[Address]) 
    VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Address)
```

Additionally stored procedure `add` is also reserved. Best option is to re-name the `table/sp` name.

**EDIT :**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add] (
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Email NVARCHAR(50),
    @Address NVARCHAR (300) 
)
AS
    INSERT INTO [User] ([Name],[Email],[Address]) 
           VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Address)
```

Comment: Still getting error

Comment: @KaranPophale. . . What error you are getting ?

Comment: stored procedure  has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[User].[,@Name,@Email,@Address]

Comment: yes now it works, thank you

Comment: `ADD` is also a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); should probably change that too (and it's a really non-descriptive name for an SP).

Answer (score 0):

`UserId` column is `NOT NULL`, that's why you are getting the error.

(1) Make your `UserID` column `IDENTITY`(auto increment) Or Nullable

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserId]  INT            IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]   NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Address] NVARCHAR (300) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)

);
```

(2) remove Quotes from SP,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add]
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Email NVARCHAR(50),
    @Address NVARCHAR (300)
AS
    INSERT INTO [User]([Name],[Email],[Address]) VALUES (@Name,@Email,@Address)
RETURN 0
```